# How to set attribute in jquery after dom ready?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to checkbox checked in jquery after dom ready.
I used dashboard template for responsive user interface.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#genderF").attr("checked",true);
});
```

html code here

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 8px;">
 M:
 <input type="radio" class="flat" name="gender" id="genderM" value="M" checked="" required /> F:
 <input type="radio" class="flat" name="gender" id="genderF" value="F" />
</div>
```

But it doesn't work well.
I have to checkbox checked in static html file.
And how to change checked state in jquery?
As i mentioned before, i used dashboard template for ui effect and they make more elements for checkbox so even though i can set attribute to checkbox, it doesn't work well as i expected.
 I used gentelella dashboard template. [colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/form.html](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/form.html) here I used checkbox and want to change state in jquery. I 'd be very glad if anyone help me

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: Please show the HTML. The above will work (although it relies on `attr` doing some special handling for you) if you have `<input type="checkbox" id="genderM">`.

Comment: @j08691: They should on principal, but it won't make any difference. `attr` has special handling (even in v3.x) for `checked` (and `disabled` and `selected`).

Comment: @WhiteSnow T.J. is right, and my comment is just a note about what is now normally used, however you need to create a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k3gtx4ky/

Comment: Thanks, I used gentelella dashboard template.
https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/form.html
here I used checkbox and want to change state in jquery.
I 'd be very glad if anyone help me

Comment: People will be happy to help you if you do as @j08691 said: Put a [mcve] **in** the question, with a clear description of what isn't working. Make it **runnable** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Answer (score -1):

$( "#x" ).prop( "checked", true );

Comment: While they should use `prop` on general principal, they don't have to, not even with jQuery 3.x; `attr` has special-case handling for `checked` (and `selected`, and `disabled`). This isn't what's wrong.